# Bounties for tag: Marvel Cinematic Universe

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

In about a month, the next *Avengers* film, *Avengers: Age of Ultron* will be released.  To celebrate and prepare for the occasion, I'd like to do a promotion of [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) posts. I hope this draws attention to this tag, and encourages some additional posts.

The promotion is simple, I ask y'all to post answers here on Meta highlighting questions and answers in this tag that are, like Thor, **worthy**.  Which is to say, posts that are interesting, high-quality, or just in general impressive.  Post a link and a short blurb about what you like about the post, and the community can then vote on your nomination.

I will then place bounties on the highest posts to draw attention to them on the Main site.  The number and value of the bounties will depend on how many posts get nominated.

Let me know what questions/comments you have either by commenting below, or by @mentioning me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19346/agents-of-nothing), where I frequently hang out.

<sub>This is inspired by a similar promotion over on [Anime.SE](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2281).</sub>

Comment: I can also throw in some bounty-love if need be!

Comment: I got a bunch of awesome information about Toad's spit, if that helps...

Comment: @keen great job. More than happy to chip-in with bounties if needed :)

Comment: Interesting I saw this right after posting http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84910/how-did-skyes-watch-work-here. But it's not really Mjolnir-level.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76538/whats-with-thanos-headquarters

Comment: [Whose fist dent is there on the seclusion retreat cabin of S.H.I.E.L.D.?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86317/whose-fist-dent-is-there-on-the-seclusion-retreat-cabin-of-s-h-i-e-l-d)

For the word-of-god answer.

Answer (score 10):

Jason Baker posted [this excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85464/1027) about why there haven't been more Hulk films in the MCU since *The Incredible Hulk*.  I especially like the research he did to compare the Hulk films against the rest of the MCU.

Comment: I'll also award a bounty to this answer soon..

Answer (score 4):

This question makes a good, clearly-explained point about the plot of *The Winter Soldier*, and gets a detailed answer that I think explains it:

- [What is the Lemurian Star really doing in Captain America: The Winter Soldier?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76922/what-is-the-lemurian-star-really-doing-in-captain-america-the-winter-soldier)

Answer (score 3):

I quite liked this one that asked what Groot is, having done some research:

- [What Species is Groot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82085/what-species-is-groot)

The accepted answer has page grabs and everything.

Answer (score 3):

And I think this one asking about all of Stan Lee’s cameos is pretty fun, with decently-sourced answers (they got the word of The Watcher! I mean God!):

- [Is Stan Lee playing the Watcher in all his cameos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76303/is-stan-lee-playing-the-watcher-in-all-his-cameos)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a huge fan of nuances and phrasings, so I enjoyed answering the question:

[What did Loki mean when he called Natasha (Black Widow) “Drakov's daughter”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33546/what-did-loki-mean-when-he-called-natasha-black-widow-drakovs-daughter/33549#33549)